# Match 2 fields in different files

Tags: linux, unix, join, awk

I have 2 files like this:

File A:

```
1,x
2,z
3,y
```

File B:

```
7,b
3,c
9,t
1,m
```

I would like to loop through `File A` *(first columns)* and see if there any matches in `File B` *(first columns)* using `awk`.

The expected will be:

```
1,m
3,c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($1 in a)' file1 file2
3,c
1,m
```

Pipe to `sort` for ordered output:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($1 in a)' file1 file2 | sort
1,m
3,c
```

---

Alternatively this is what `join` does *(requires input files to be sorted)*:

```
$ join <(sort file1) <(sort file2) -j1 -t, -o"2.1,2.2"
1,m
3,c
```

Answer (score 2):

```
join -t, -o 1.1,1.2 <(sort fileA) <(sort fileB)
```